# If death lifts the caster's spells, then how are the Horcruxes still defended?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, horcrux

1. *Half-Blood Prince* clearly establishes that death lifts the caster's spells.
2. Voldemort died quite early in the series.
3. It follows that Voldemort's spells, such as the protections on his horcruxes, should've been lifted.
4. Throughout the series, Voldemort's Horcruxes still work and have their protections on them. This is true even before we see Voldemort think about checking in on his Horocruxes.
5. #3 appears to contradict #4.

What is the resolution of this?

Comment: You did read the books, right?  It's clearly established that while Voldemort's body was destroyed when he tried to kill Harry, he didn't actually die.  He says so himself near the end of book 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Your theory rests on incorrect facts**

TL/DR: Spells can survive the death of the caster, and Voldemort technically didn't "die" until the end of the series anyway.

Your first statement, that " *Half-Blood Prince* clearly establishes that death lifts the caster's spells." is erroneous.  HBP establishes that SOME spells end upon the death of the caster.  But it is also known that other spells very specifically continue to work after the death of the caster.  In *Order of the Phoenix* Sirius' mother's portrait is hanging in the entryway and Sirius states that he is unable to remove it because of the permanent sticking charm his mother placed upon it even though his mother is deceased.  In *Chamber of Secrets* it is implied that the chamber opens magically upon Harry's speaking parseltongue, in which case the spell has continued to be in effect for a thousandish years after the death of the caster!

Your second point, that Voldemort died quiet early in the series, is also debatable.    A Horcrux very specifically prevents you from dying because of the parts of your soul anchored to the Horcrux/s.  As HP very clearly considers the soul "you" and your body something your soul inhabits (Based on how various wizards talk about Sirius, Harry and Dumbledore's conversation in *Deathly Hallows* post-harry being Avada Kadavra'd again, Voldemort's own statements re: death, etc) Voldemort never died in the true sense until the end of *Deathly Hallows*.

It therefor follows that Voldemort's defensive spells would work because he never truly died. Even if he had died, we have no indication which, if any, of his defensive spells would have ceased to function upon his death.

Answer (score 7):

I would say that premise #2 is wrong: Voldemort did not die until near the end of DH.

I am also not sure where in HBP it is "clearly established" that death lifts the caster's spells.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Dumbledore's death at the end of book 6 terminates the effect of the spell he cast to immobilize Harry.

Comment: That's true - but showing that a single spell was cancelled on his death doesn't necessarily mean all of them will be. Hogwarts appears to be a whole pile of enchantments, many of which Dumbledore had at least some control over - but no indication that they had to be renewed when he died...

Answer (score 0):

this is simple he wasn't dead he was simply ripped from his body he wasn't dead because of the horcuz. As he wasnt dead none of hid spells were lifted,

Comment: [Dario Quint's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/270856/122024) already made this same point, and went into significantly more detail. There's not much point in posting a new answer if you don't have anything to add that wasn't said in one or more previous answers.

Comment: With that said, welcome to SF&F and terrific that you want to contribute and help others here!  With a little time, you'll get used to the way we work and hopefully enjoy....